# When submitting form action doesn't follow after onsubmit code

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I have a little form on my website but when I submit, the onsubmit executes but it never ends which is good because it is a loading icon. But it won't execute my action code so what is wrong in my code so that I would get my onsubmit active followed by the action command which the php file brings me to a succes page. (php file is ok). Thanks in advance!

```
<script 
type="text/javascript">
function showHide() {
var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
if (div.style.display == 'none') {
div.style.display = '';
}
else {
div.style.display = 'none';
return false;
}
}
</script>

<form name="form2" method="POST" onsubmit="showHide(); return false;" action="\JocanasNLsuggest.php">    
Ideeën voor nieuwe films, TV-series games of functies:<br><textarea class="input" name="comment" rows="5" cols="30" required></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Voorstellen" name="submit">
</form>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
<div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should have a forward slash, not a backslash in the `action` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning false from an event handler assigned with an intrinsic event attribute will prevent the default action.

In this case, the default action is submitting the form.

… and you are returning false from the function:

> ```
> onsubmit="showHide(); return false;"
> ```

… so just don't do that.